# How to to style dropdown menu in material-ui Nativeselect?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to to style dropdown menu in material-ui select component, I want to be able to change the default color of that menu but using  "&:not([multiple]) option": {background: "yellow"} is not working,
and also to push down the drop menu since it goes on the the top of label ?

[image: Codesandbox Example]

Comment: It is native to the browser, you cannot style this. I'm using chrome on mac and the dropdown is rounded. Use the normal Select component and you'll have the ability to change the style. Also, "radius" is spelled incorrectly in that sample.

Comment: @steve , so native in this case means native to the browser that is opening the menu, the problem with the select in v4 it goes on top of the component and in my app it is bad for user experience.

Comment: I believe so. If you just add a basic HTML select component and try it in different browsers, you will see they are all different because they use the built-in element. I'll post an answer shortly that should help this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize and provide a solution to the issue from the comments.

NativeSelect is using the browser's default select element. For example, check out [how this looks](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) on different browsers.

The solution would be to use the [Select](https://v4.mui.com/components/selects/) component in Material UI.

You mention the issue is that the menu appears over the top of the component making it not so desirable. To fix that you can add to the MenuProps prop of the Select component.

```
MenuProps={{
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left"
  },
  transformOrigin: {
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "left"
  },
  getContentAnchorEl: null
}}
```

Here we are saying the top left of the popup menu, should anchor to the bottom left of the select component. The documentation lacks for this trick...

[Check it out here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jbhmf?file=/demo.js).

`getContentAnchorEl: null` is required although I can't tell you much about it. Hopefully, someone reading this can let us know.